# Selenium Java: Checkbox in MikroTik

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, webdriver

[image: Mikrotik chekbox]

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

driver.get("http://192.168.*.*/webfig/#Wireless.Interfaces.6");

driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#content > table.list > tbody:nth-child(41) > tr > td.label > span));
```

This is selector from Chrome DevelopMode. How to click on this checkbox?

Comment: Provide your error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.checkbox input")).click();
```

As, `span` tag has a class attribute `.checkbox` it can be used as above.
We need to click the `input` tag with `type='checkbox'.`